# Install Asp.net core Runtime not working on ubuntu linux OS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ubuntu-18.04, asp.net-core-3.1

I tried to install asp.net core 3.1 runtime on linux ubuntue 18.4 lts and used this commands to install asp.net core runtime.

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-3.1
```

after that every thing installed without any issue but when I want to check asp.net core version on ubuntu os I run this command

```
dotnet --version
```

I getting the following massage I have no idea about that I am not installed asp.net core SDK I need to install Runtime to run my web site

```
dotnet --version
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet` is CLI is driver for CLI interface included with [`the .NET Core SDK.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/), so you need to [install it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

You have only installed runtime which is needed to run apps that were made with  ASP.NET Core that didn't include the runtime itself.

Comment: So I should just install SDK only or both ?

Comment: @MR_WELL depends on what you need. If you going to develop some .NET stuff you better install SDK (AFAIK it includes the runtime). If you want only to run already created and compiled app - runtime should be fine.